# Why is AES more secure than DES?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, symmetric-key

I am beginning to learn crypto algorithms and I understand how the above mentioned algorithms work. Is it that the key length of AES is longer? Which steps of AES encryption makes it less vulnerable than DES?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

DES was designed with an effective key length of 56 bits, which is vulnerable to [exhaustive search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker). It also has some weaknesses against differential and linear cryptanalysis: these allow to recover the key using, respectively, 2<sup>47</sup> chosen plaintexts, or 2<sup>43</sup> known plaintexts. A *known plaintext* is an encrypted block (an 8-byte block, for DES) for which the attacker knows the corresponding decrypted block. A *chosen plaintext* is a kind of known plaintext where the attacker gets to choose himself the decrypted block. In practical attack conditions, such huge amounts of known or chosen plaintexts cannot really be obtained, hence differential and linear cryptanalysis do not really impact the actual security of DES; the weakest point is the short key. Still, the existence of those attacks, which, from an *academic point of view*, have less complexity than the exhaustive key search (which uses 2<sup>55</sup> invocations on average), is perceived as a lack in security.

As a side note, differential analysis was known to the DES designers, and DES was hardened against it (hence the "good score" of 2<sup>47</sup>). With today's standards, we would consider it as "not good enough" because it is now academic tradition to require attack complexity above exhaustive search. Still, the DES designers were really good. They did not know about linear cryptanalysis, which was discovered by Matsui in 1992, and linear cryptanalysis is more effective on DES than differential cryptanalysis, and yet is devilishly difficult to apply in practice (2<sup>43</sup> known plaintext blocks, that's 64 terabytes...).

The structural weaknesses of DES are thus its key size, and its short block size: with *n*-bit blocks, some encryption modes begin to have trouble when 2<sup>*n*/2</sup> blocks are encrypted with the same key. For the 64-bit DES blocks, this occurs after encrypting 32 gigabytes worth of data, a big but not huge number (yesterday, I bought a harddisk which is thirty times bigger than that).

A variant on DES is called 3DES: that's, more or less, three DES instances in a row. This solves the key size issue: a 3DES key consists in 168 bits (nominally 192 bits, out of which 24 bits are supposed to serve as parity check, but are in practice wholly ignored), and exhaustive search on a 168-bit key is wholly out of reach of human technology. From (again) an academic point of view, there is an attack with cost 2<sup>112</sup> on 3DES, which is not feasible either. Differential and linear cryptanalysis are defeated by 3DES (their complexity rises quite a bit with the number of rounds, and 3DES represents 48 rounds, vs 16 for the plain DES).

Yet 3DES still suffers from the block size issues of DES. Also, it is quite slow (DES was meant for hardware implementations, not software, and 3DES is even three times slower than DES).

Thus, AES was defined with the following requirements:

- 128-bit blocks (solves issues with CBC)
- accepts keys of size 128, 192 and 256 bits (128 bits are enough to resist exhaustive key search; the two other sizes are mostly a way to comply to rigid US military regulations)
- has no academic weakness worse than exhaustive key search
- should be as fast as 3DES (AES turned out to be much faster than 3DES in software, typically 5 to 10 times faster)

The resistance of AES towards differential and linear cryptanalysis comes from a better "avalanche effect" (a bit flip at some point quickly propagates to the complete internal state) and specially crafted, bigger "S-boxes" (a *S-box* is a small lookup table used within the algorithm, and is an easy way to add non-linearity; in DES, S-boxes have 6-bit inputs and 4-bit outputs; in AES, S-boxes have 8-bit inputs and 8-bit outputs). The design of the AES benefited from 25 years of insights and research on DES. Also, the AES was chosen through an open competition with 15 candidates from as many research teams around the world, and the total amount of brain resources allocated to that process was tremendous. The original DES designers were genius, but one could say that the aggregate effort of cryptographers for the AES has been far greater.

On a philosophical point of view, we could say that what makes a cryptographic primitive secure is the amount of effort invested in its design. At least, that effort is what creates the *perception of security*: when I use a cryptosystem, I want it to be secure, but I also want to be *certain* that it is secure (I want to sleep at night). The public design and analysis process helps quite a lot in building that trust. NIST (the US body for standardization of such things) learned that lesson well, and decided to again choose an open competition for [SHA-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/).